# Resetting Tornado IOLoop PeriodicCallback time

Tags: python, tornado

Right now, the callback is called every 1 sec, as can be seen in the below snippet

```
ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop()
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient(ioloop)
callback = lambda: self.fire_request(http_client)
timer = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback,1000, ioloop)
timer.start()
```

However, is it possible to reset this callback time to 0.5 sec, during runtime, by something like:

```
timer.set_callbacktime(500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the interval, but you can stop the first PeriodicCallback and start a new one.